# Decimal? remove trailing zeroes

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert this `decimal? largeValue` into just `569` but when I use `Truncate` I am getting the error "can't convert decimal? to decimal"

Is this the correct way to remove the trailing zeroes?

```
decimal? Value = 569;
decimal? largeValue = 569.0000M;
decimal? outValue;
outValue = decimal?.Truncate(largeValue);
```

Comment: Try `largeValue.Value`.  A `decimal?` can hold the value of a decimal or be `null`.  The value is in the `Value` property.  If you want to check whether the `decimal?` has a value (i.e., is not null), look at the `HasValue` property

Comment: Your example does not compile. You can't treat the type `decimal` as a nullable, as you write on the last line (` = decimal?` ). `Truncate` also requires a `decimal` value, not a `decimal?`.

Comment: Also, you aren't going to be "removing trailing zeros" by saving a decimal back to a decimal. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQKt3k You'd need to format the value as a string, and remove zeros during that conversion.

Comment: @gunr2171 ? `1m` and `1.00m` are two *different* `decimal` values... Why did you say you can't do that?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  How are `1m` and `1.00m` different (in value).  They are both literal representations of the decimal value of `1`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov They seem equal to me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WwIZcZ

Comment: @Flydog57 I agree that my comment was @#$@ lazy. Indeed it should be more elaborate and I should not have used "value" which indeed can be understood differently. The particular interpretation I was trying to achieve is "those two numbers stored differently in `decimal` format preserving that number of zeros in each. While values of those two numbers are the same from math point of view the "decimal values" are different. It is easy to see by converting them to  string for example which would lead to "1" and "1.00" correspondingly". Sorry for not being clear from the start.

Comment: Guess I learned something today as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nullable value types have a `Value` property that holds the value (if there is one) and a `HasValue` property that indicates that the variable is not null (and consequently, has a value).  This code compiles and works:

```
decimal? value = 569;
decimal? largeValue = 569.0000M;
Debug.Assert(largeValue.HasValue);
Debug.Assert(value == largeValue);
decimal? outValue;
outValue = decimal.Truncate(largeValue.Value);
```

Note that the call to `Truncate` does nothing to affect the value (though it does get rid of the excess zeros stored in the decimal representation of the number).  However that both `569m` and `569.0000m` represent the same number.

I've been corrected (by @alexeilevenkov).  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal:

> The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.

You learn something new every day!

Comment: @alexeilevenkov: Are you commenting about my note about `Truncate`?  Calling `Truncate(569.0000m)` will yield `569m`.  However `569.0000m == 569m`.  How is that misleading.  That's why I added the `Debug.Assert(value == largeValue);`; those two values are equal!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I stand corrected.  Thanks for pointing this out.  I've updated my answer (hopefully to your satisfaction).  I will have been working with the .NET framework for 20 years at the end of next month - I never noticed that "feature" before